Delaying 50 Laravel Cron So They Wont Running in The Same Time
I have around 50 websites which is running cron every 2 hours to generate sitemap. Well, I set those 50 websites into a cron job
Something like this
* * * * * cd /home/ita/public_html/domain.com && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

The problem is, those 50 cron seem together which lead to high server usages. I know the cron is running each minute but Laravel cron wont running because it is set to 2 hours.
Here is the laravel kernel console code
$schedule->call(fn () => SitemapController::index())->everyTwoHours()->name('buildSitemap')->withoutOverlapping();

How can Laravel cron not running together to build sitemap? I am thinking about making a random sleep in the process.
        $schedule->call(function (){
            sleep(rand(0,120));
            SitemapController::index();
        })->everyTwoHours()->name('buildSitemap')->withoutOverlapping();

Is it appropriate to do? Or is there any solution? Thank you

you have 50 websites in the same server?

Yeah, its just a simple website which mostly showing a cached content (saved in Redis). I am using a dedicated server

and how long do this command run for?

maybe split the 50 sites into groups, and offset each group by a few minutes

it runs in ~3 sec but the problem is they are all running in the same time. So, i am trying to find out how to run 5 of them in each group rather than running those 50 in the same time.

You can apply an offset to the everyTwoHours method
// Running every 2 hours starting at 0:00, offset by 5 minutes each
$schedule->command('sitemap:generate --from=1 --to=10')->everyTwoHours(); // 2:00, 4:00, 6:00, etc.
$schedule->command('sitemap:generate --from=11 --to=20')->everyTwoHours(5); // 2:05, 4:05, 6:05, etc.
$schedule->command('sitemap:generate --from=21 --to=30')->everyTwoHours(10); // 2:10, 4:10, 6:10, etc.
$schedule->command('sitemap:generate --from=31 --to=40')->everyTwoHours(15); // 2:15, 4:15, 6:15, etc.
$schedule->command('sitemap:generate --from=41 --to=50')->everyTwoHours(20); // 2:20, 4:20, 6:20, etc.
$schedule->command('sitemap:generate --from=51 --to=60')->everyTwoHours(25); // 2:25, 4:25, 6:25, etc.
...

Or depending on how your data is stored you can make it more dynamic with a loop, and calculating the offset/chunks based on the count of sites

@raden-bagus was this answer usefull?
